# meta post search

Tags: search, post-meta

I need to query post meta fields, filtered by a multi checkbox

[image: (image)]

Currently, the query works only with second parameter (People) when the form is submitted.

How can I filter with two parameters?

HTML (Form submit)

```
<input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1"  name="category[]" value="Planet">
<input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" name="category[]" value="People">
```

PHP (Search)

```
                $category = $_GET['category'];

                $category_planet = $category[0];
                $category_people = $category[1];

                $argsearch      = array();                    
                $argsearch["post_type"] = "projects";
                $argsearch['showposts'] = -1;

                if( $advtext!="" ){
                    $advtxtQuery ="select ID from $wpdb->posts
                    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id where {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish'  ";
                    $where =" (( post_typs LIKE 'projects') AND ( post_title LIKE '%".$advtext."%')) ";
                    $where .=" AND ( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_cmb_project_category' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%".$advtext."%')";
                    $mypostids = $wpdb->get_col($advtxtQuery." AND ( ".$where." )" );


                    if(count($mypostids)>0){
                        $argsearch['post__in']=$mypostids;
                    }else{
                        $argsearch["s"] = $advtext;
                    }

                }

                if( $category_planet!="" ){
                    if(!isset($argsearch["meta_query"])){
                        $argsearch["meta_query"] = array();
                    }
                    $argsearch["meta_query"][] = array(
                            'key' => '_cmb_project_category',
                            'value' => $category_planet,
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    );

                }


                if( $category_people!="" ){
                     if(!isset($argsearch["meta_query"])){
                          $argsearch["meta_query"] = array();
                     }
                     $argsearch["meta_query"][] = array(
                               'key' => '_cmb_project_category',
                               'value' => $category_people,
                               'compare' => 'LIKE'
                     );

                }

                global $wp_query, $post,$wpdb;
                $query =  new WP_Query($argsearch);
                while($query->have_posts()):
                    $query->next_post();
                $project_list = $query->post->ID;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @toscho for help to improve my question I'm not good in English.

Thank you very much. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your `$advtxtQuery` query-- `$where =" (( post_typs LIKE 'projects')...`

For the rest, both queries are searching on the same key so use `IN` instead of trying to create two separate arrays, as in the [Codex example below](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters):

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
   'meta_key' => 'age',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'age',
           'value' => array(3, 4),
           'compare' => 'IN',
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

You could just pass your `$category` as is but I'd filter it for maliciousness. In fact, your values are (or seem to be) static so the safest thing is to do this:

```
$category_args = array();
if(!empty($category[0])) $category_args[] = "Planet";
if(!empty($category[1])) $category_args[] = "People";
```

And pass that into your query like so:

```
if( !empty($category_args) ){
  if(!isset($argsearch["meta_query"])){
      $argsearch["meta_query"] = array();
  }
  $argsearch["meta_query"][] = array(
      'key' => '_cmb_project_category',
      'value' => $category_args,
      'compare' => 'IN'
  );
}
```